# Copy/Paste cells next to cells that have certain string

Tags: vba, copy, range, paste

I am trying to look up cells in a certain column that have a string (e.g. Names), copy the corresponding cells in the column to its right (i.e. offset(0,1) ), then paste it to a column in a different sheet.  I have the following code to find the range variable that I want.  However, I can't select it from a different sheet!
When I use `Sheets(1).MyRange.Copy`, it doesn't accept it.  Am I referring to the range in a wrong way?  What am I doing wrong?

Here's code that I use to get MyRange:

```
Option Explicit

Sub SelectByValue(Rng1 As Range, Value As Double)

Dim MyRange As Range
Dim Cell As Object

 'Check every cell in the range for matching criteria.
For Each Cell In Rng1
    If Cell.Value = Value Then
        If MyRange Is Nothing Then
            Set MyRange = Range(Cell.Address)
        Else
            Set MyRange = Union(MyRange, Range(Cell.Address))
        End If
    End If
Next


End Sub

Sub CallSelectByValue()

 'Call the macro and pass all the required variables to it.
 'In the line below, change the Range, Minimum Value, and Maximum Value as needed
Call SelectByValue(Sheets(1).Range("A1:A20"), "Tom")

End Sub
```

One More Question: Rather than specifying the exact range to look at (e.g. "A1:A20"), I would LOVE to look at all of column A.  But I don't want to use ("A:A") so it wouldn't look at all rows of A.  Isn't there a method to look only in cells that have entries in column A?

Thank you VERY much.

Al

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only need `MyRange.Copy`.

To restrict only to cells in column A which might have values, you could use

```
With Sheet1
   Set rngToSearch = Application.Intersect(.Columns(1), .UsedRange)
  End With
```

...or maybe look at .SpecialsCells()

Comment: Hi Tim, thanks for the response.  With regards to the first point, I actually run this Macro in sheet2, but I need to copy the corresponding MyRange from Sheet1 into Sheet2. When I use Sheets(1).MyRange.Copy, it doesn't work.  Do you know the correct way to write it?

Comment: To be clear, let's assume that MyRange was (B1:B4), I want to be able to copy this MyRange from any sheet that I used (e.g. "B1:B4" on sheet 1, or 3, or..etc.)

Comment: If you want to copy MyRange, then just use MyRange.Copy  You don't need the sheet qualifier.